# Why does 1 of these getter/setters work and the others don't

Tags: swift, getter-setter

I have a class which has 2 sets of getter & setters. 1 set is the traditional type. These work as expected:

```
var userEmail : String
{
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profileEmail) ?? ""
    }
    set (newValue) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profileEmail)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}

var podSerialNum : Int
{
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodSN)
    }
    set (newValue) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodSN)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
var podID : Int
{
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodID)
    }
    set (newValue) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodID)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

The other gets/sets all properties at once.

```
var userProfile: (email:String?, podSn:String?, podId:String?)
{
    get {
        return ( UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profileEmail) as? String,
                 UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodSN) as? String,
                 UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodID) as? String)
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.email,   forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profileEmail)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.podSn,     forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodSN)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.podId,   forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodID)

        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

`userProfile.podSn` always returns nil. However `userProfile.email` & `userProfile.podId` work as expected. Also, the direct getter (`podSerialNum`) works.

What am I missing?

Comment: `as? String` => `as? Int` for the one that are Integers. Else, if like doing `let myInt = 3; let t = myInt as? String`. What's the value of `t`?

Comment: @Larme 't' goes into a TextField, so it should (ultimately) be a String. I will make your suggested change. I'll post my results, but I'm sure this will work. thank you!

Comment: Then, it's `String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodSN))` and so on.

Comment: @Larme Works like a charm. Swift 101. Thank you!

Comment: @Bassman no need to force synchronize

Comment: @LeoDabus good to know - thank you. I added that because the app has network communication. I was unsure if there would be sync issues across multiple threads.

Comment: @Larme Your comment solved my issue. If you convert it to an answer I will Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a few steps to understand:

```
UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodSN) as? String
```

=>

```
let podSNFromUserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodSN)
let podSNAsString = podSNFromUserDefaults as? String
```

Well, you'll see that `podSNFromUserDefaults` is not `nil`, it's `podSNAsString` which is.
Why ? Because `podSNFromUserDefaults` is an `Int`/`NSNumber`, not a `String`. You can't cast it as a `String` like that. Use `String(myInt)`.

And since we already know it's an Int, like you did for each single call, use `integer(forKey:)`, and directly `string(forKey:)` also for the `profileEmail`, you don't need the `as? String` afterwards.

```
var userProfile: (email: String?, podSn: String?, podId: String?)
{
    get {
        return (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profileEmail),
                String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodSN)),
                String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.profilePodID))
    }
}
```

Side note:
You should get rid of the `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()`.

Tip:
If you have issues, don't forget to break multiple calls made in one line into various ones. It should be then easier to debug which step exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.