# Firebase & Swift - reading data returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm currently trying to read data from a realtime database. The function below is being called after the user has successfully logged in.

The database is structured as following:

```
driven
     - users
          - uid
              - monthlyStartKm
              - currentKm
              ...
```

I have following code to read the data:

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let monthlyStartKmData = value?["monthlyStartKm"] as? String ?? ""
            let currentKmData = value?["currentKm"] as? String ?? ""
            ....
```

Somehow monthlyStartKmData & currentKmData return `nil`. **What is it I've forgotten?**

**Edit:**
`print(value)` prints the following:

```
Optional({
    monthlyStartKm = 15000;
    currentKm = 15250;
    ...
})
```

**Second edit:**
It's being saved like this, both startKm and currentKm are of type `Int`:

```
let userObject = [
            "monthlyStartKm": startKm,
            "currentKm": currentKm,
            ...
        ] as [String: Any]
```

Comment: Print `value` to let us see what's inside it?

Comment: @Larme I've edited my question with `print(value)`.

Comment: Are you sure `monthlyStartKm` is a String? It's not an `Int`?

Comment: @Larme  No, it's initially being saved as a Int - but if I try: `.. as? Int ?? ""` I get following error: `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'`.

Comment: Then `let intValue = value?["monthlyStartKm"] as? Int ?? 0; let stringValue = String(intValue)`. A cast is not an init. You don't transform Int to String or String to Int the way you did.

Comment: @Larme It works, thank you! In case you want to create an answer for me to approve, I will.

Comment: It's the same logic as there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300399/why-does-1-of-these-getter-setters-work-and-the-others-dont/55356011#55356011